# node.js and express. Serve html5 video with mp4 & ogg files that are not directly accessible

Tags: html, node.js, video, express

I'm using node and express. I want to control the access to the video files in a way that they will reside on the public folder (so they can be served to the client) but also not be directly accessible by non-authorized users through a url on the browser.

I want to serve the videos to the client using the usual html5 video tag:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="mp4 video file" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="ogg video file" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Is this possible? How can it be implemented?
Thanks

**----------------------- Solved this way: ---------------------**

Solved it using middleware. Is was much simpler than I though it would be.

I placed the files on the videos folder residing on the public folder of my app. Though I added this line to my application.js file:

```
app.get('/videos/*', authenticationFunction(), function(req, res, next) {
    next();
});
```

The authenticationFunction checks if the user is allowed or not to access any file on the videos folder.

The authenticationFunction looks like this:

```
var authenticationFunction = function(){
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if(the user is authorized to access the files){
            return next();
        } else{
            return next(new Error('unauthorized video access'));
        }
    }
}
```

Finally on the app configuration on the app.use function I added an "unauthorized video access" error handling part.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Declare it as a static assets folder:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'videos/'));
```

Example:

```
videos/
  ├── vid1
  │
  ├── vid2
  │
  └── vid3


public/
  ├── css/
  │     ├── ...
  │     └── ...
  ├── js/
  │     ├── ...
  │     └── ...
  └── img/
        ├── ...
        └── ....
```